# Twitter Bootstrap Css fix height of a child according to parent row-fluid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, height, parent

is there a better way to fix the height of a child to the main parent height?
I tryed so but it doesn't works for me:

```
.child {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #5B6567;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    position: relative !important;
    text-align: center;
    width: 12%;
    height:100%
}

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="child">
        child
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WTmt6/1/
check I want the grey left div to fix the height of the red one big .media div
ps: I can't use fixed/px dimensions I only use percentage/% on my layout

Comment: How that isn't working for you? I copied your code into jsfiddle and it works.

Comment: this works, child has the same height as parent. Am I missing anything? http://jsfiddle.net/qRPYt/

Comment: sorry i updated question i'm on twitter bootstrap check it now

Comment: Don't keep changing your question and code display, you won't get any help.

Comment: @Caelea what u mean? i need to leave there a wrong code or i need to put the right code i'm using?

Comment: @Badaboooooom your first code was working, at least write an "Later edit" or we won't be able to understand anything.

Comment: ok, right now the question is it ok, cause i'm using twitter bootstrap and i missed the parent was .row-fluid element, FORGET first code i showed up, it was my fault

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WTmt6/1/

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure if I understand the problem...
First of all, remove the padding on `child` as it is going to cause trouble with the `height:100%`. You should add the padding in an inner div:

```
.inner {
    padding:6px;
}

<div class="child">
    <div class="inner">child</div>
</div>
```

The height 100% is working fine. Here is an example of 3 childs (two of them are equal), floating inside a floating parent without problems: http://jsfiddle.net/qRPYt/7/

If you are still having trouble, please, post the CSS of `row-fluid` or even better, a jsfiddle.

Comment: i tryed with inner div but it doesn't works anyway really can't understand what's up :/

Comment: create a jsfiddle please: http://jsfiddle.net (paste the relevant code, click on "Save" and post the link)

Comment: check i want the grey left div to fits the height of .media (red big one div) http://jsfiddle.net/WTmt6/

Comment: If you want divs to look like tables, use tables, it is going to be much easier. A table with 3 columns and 1 row will solve your problem.

Comment: fight with DIV's then xD It's not a good idea to use tables everywhere, but when you need a table you don't have to use divs to be "cool".